# PHP - $this stops to work after adding a specific line

Tags: php

This is my code which in this form is not working:

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_grid_collection')
        ->addFieldToSelect('entity_id')
        ->addFieldToSelect('increment_id')
        ->addFieldToSelect('customer_id')
        ->addFieldToSelect('customer_email')
        ->addFieldToSelect('created_at')
        ->addFieldToSelect('grand_total')
        ->addFieldToSelect('base_grand_total')
        ->addFieldToSelect('status')
        ->addFieldToSelect('order_currency_code')
        ->addFieldToSelect('store_id')
        ->addFieldToSelect('billing_name')
        ->addFieldToSelect('shipping_name')
        ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', Mage::registry('current_customer')->getId())
        ->setIsCustomerMode(true);


    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}

protected function _avansFilter($collection, $column)
    {
     if (!$value = $column->getFilter()->getValue()) {
                return $this;
            }
            $orderId = $collection->getData();
            $CustomerEmail = $orderId[0]['customer_email'];

            $this->getCollection()->getSelect()->where(
                "order.increment_id like ?"
            , "%$value%");



            return $this;

    }
```

When i remove `$orderId = $collection->getData();` the function `_avansFilter` is starting to return results, but i have to reach the data in the $collection so i can make a proper results.

Somehow `$collection` and `$this` are not compatible but i do not know why.

Maybe it is very silly question but i do not know how can i resolve it.

I need to get the data from `$collection` to be used inside `function _avansFilter` but when i use this data inside the function it is stopping to return the correct results using `return $this;`

Looking forward for your advices and answers.

Kind regards

Comment: what does the function return otherwise, or do you get a blank page instead?

Comment: `!$value = $column->getFilter()->getValue()` — Are you aware that you are using an assignment operator? I assume you mean `!$value == $column->getFilter()->getValue()`?

Comment: If you are setting/creating/preparing the collection via `$this->setCollection`, then I’d assume there is also a counterpart to that method available, `$this->getCollection` …?

Comment: @CBroe yes exactly.

Comment: @MCEmperor Assignment makes more sense in this case. Assign, test if false, otherwise use it later.

Comment: Can u please dump the result from $collection->getData().

Comment: Well then you should probably use that, instead of trying to access a variable named `$collection` (does that even exist?) directly.

Comment: Enable all warnings and errors, and debug the value of $collection, and the return of getData().

Comment: @TonyStark I would recommend not using an assignment operator inside an `if` condition, it will make your code harder to read and more prone to errors.

Comment: Can someone make an complete answer because i do not get it at all. Please tell me if i have to provide more information.

Comment: @TonyStark What do you mean by "stopping to return the correct results"? What does it return otherwise?

Comment: Should be closed as typo

Comment: If you do indeed get a “blank page” only (asked in first comment, but no proper reply yet), then this means you have a fatal error in your script. In that case, go enable proper error reporting/logging first of all.